# ASP.NET my datatable loses data during for cycle

Tags: asp.net, datatable, webforms

Good morning.
I'm in trouble with datatables in a web form application.
I need to create a multi page pdf (using itext7) so i've created a datatable through an object:

```
 Private Function GetConnection() As SQLiteConnection
    Return New SQLiteConnection("Data source=" & HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") & "db.db; Version = 3;")
End Function
Private Function Seleziona(ByRef query As String) As DataTable
    Dim cnn As SQLiteConnection = GetConnection()
    Try
        Dim dt As DataTable
        cnn.Open()
        Dim cmd = cnn.CreateCommand()
        Dim sda = New SQLiteDataAdapter(query, cnn)
        ds.Reset()
        sda.Fill(ds)
        dt = ds.Tables(0)
        Return dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        ds.Dispose()
        cnn.Close()
        cnn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

The calling code is as follows:

```
Public Sub CreaElencoZonaGialla(ByRef dest As String, Optional ByRef team As String = "0")
    Dim db As New GetData
   ... declarations ...
    Dim doc As New Document(pdf, PageSize.A4)
    Dim dtteams As DataTable
    If team = "0" Then
        dtteams = db.ListAll("t_societa")
    Else
        dtteams = db.ListW1Parameter("t_societa", New WebControls.ListItem("id", " = " & team))
    End If
    doc.SetMargins(25, 15, 25, 30)
    If dtteams.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim conta As Int16 = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In dtteams.Rows
            conta += 1
            If conta > 1 Then
                doc.Add(New AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE))
            End If
            ... itext code
            cell.Add(CreaTabellaPDF("t_veicoli", New WebControls.ListItem("id_team = ", row(0).ToString)))
            tbl.AddCell(cell)
            doc.Add(tbl)
        Next
    Else
        p = New Paragraph(New Text("Non ci sono team registrati")).SetFontSize(15.0F)
        doc.Add(p)
    End If





    doc.Close()
End Sub
Function CreaTabellaPDF(ByVal tabella As String, parametri As WebControls.ListItem) As Table
    Dim db2 As New GetData
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim cell As Cell
    Dim p As Paragraph
    Dim t As Text
    Dim dt As DataTable = db2.ListW1Parameter(tabella, parametri)
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        tbl = New Table(New Single() {100})
        tbl.UseAllAvailableWidth()
        cell = New Cell
        p = New Paragraph(New Text("Non ci sono record registrati"))
        cell.Add(p)
        tbl.AddCell(cell)
    Else
        tbl = New Table(New Single() {100})
        tbl.UseAllAvailableWidth()
        cell = New Cell
        p = New Paragraph(New Text("Ci sono record registrati"))
        cell.Add(p)
        tbl.AddCell(cell)
    End If


    Return tbl
End Function
```

It seems that when I load the datatable in the "CreaTabellaPDF" the other datatable (dtteams) loses data and obvoiusly gives me the error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute".
Someone can help me to find my error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the problem starts inside `GetData` that you have now show it here

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand...
GetData is the class from which I extract data with "Seleziona"... In the code I'm creating a new instance to getdata called db then i call db.SelectW1Parameter(table, parameters). Where is the error?

Comment: After googling a little I found a workaround. I've transformed the datatable in a ListOf(String) and iterating it works. But I think it's not the correct solution...